# Позиционирование элементов (занавес)

Tags: javascript

Добрый день, стоит задача написать скрипт: когда элемент A(box) достигнет позиции элемента B(curtain), добавится определенный класс элементу B.
Сам код:

```
$(window).scroll(function(){
        // Координаты Box
        var box = document.querySelector('.box');
        var coordBox = box.getBoundingClientRect();

        // Координаты Curtain
        var curtain = document.querySelector('#curtain--panel');
        var coorCurt = curtain.getBoundingClientRect();

        if(coordBox == coorCurt){
            document.querySelector('#curtain--panel .curtain--panel__left').classList.add('go_left_curtain');
            document.querySelector('#curtain--panel .curtain--panel__right').classList.add('go_right_curtain');
        }else {
            document.querySelector('#curtain--panel .curtain--panel__left').classList.remove('go_left_curtain');
            document.querySelector('#curtain--panel .curtain--panel__right').classList.remove('go_right_curtain');
        }
    });
```

Пробовал разными путями, ни в какую. В консоли ошибку не выдает. Подскажите в чем проблема?
Элемент .box имеет позицию fixed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте взять `position.top` каждого элемента и сравнить.

```
var box = document.getElementById('box').getBoundingClientRect();
top1 = box.top;
var curtain = document.getElementById('curtain--panel').getBoundingClientRect();
top2 = curtain.top;
if(top1 == top2 ){ 

}else {

}
```